# Generating a CSV file which can be opened by excel

Tags: php, excel, csv

I generate a CSV file with fputcsv function in PHP. Everything works fine except the fact that each line is one column of data in Microsoft Excel. Is there anything I can add or replace in each data so that it can be opened column per data?

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach(...){
  fputcsv($output, $csv_data);
```

CSV content is like

```
2017-01-06 14:51:15,1,2
2017-01-06 14:50:08,3,4
```

Comment: If you're working with CSV files in PHP, you won't be sorry you used this: http://csv.thephpleague.com/

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php the thrid parameter is your delimiter ....btw in excel you can use the "data" tab and import text files so you can handle your src too

Answer (score 2):

Excel will normally parse your records using the comma.

If you want to get the records into a single column, enclose them in double quotes before importing:

"2017-01-06 14:51:15,1,2"
"2017-01-06 14:50:08,3,4"

this yields:

[image]

Comment: Excel will always use the operating system setting for field separator, which is part of the international settings. In places like western Europe it's often `;`. (And, yes, that's actually pretty stupid.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  Thank you......is the double quote used to escape the separator or is it a different character ??

Comment: The more recent versions of MS Excel will recognise a `sep=,` line as the first line of the file, allowing you to use a comma as the import separator character regardless of the locale settings; but many other scripts that read csv files will treat this as an actual line of data

Comment: I'm far from being an expert in either CSV and Excel but I believe `"` works fine as delimiter in all cases. However, I think the OP's problem is the opposite of what your answer addresses: he gets what your screenshot shows, he actually wants three columns. And that's because he lives in a country where `;` is the field separator (most likely because `,` is the decimal separator).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  THANK YOU...I miss-understood the question.